# Is this an example of an undirected or directed graph? If undirected, how can it be used for arbitrage with bellman ford?

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path, bellman-ford

Hello I am learning more about graph theory and was recently learning about Bellman Ford. I noticed an example of how Bellman Ford could be used to arbitrage markets and I took some time to understand this further but I am a little confused at if the graph for arbitrage is directed or undirected. For an arbitrage opportunity between two markets to be present, there needs to be a negative cycle. However, I was reading that Bellman Ford only works with directed graphs that have negative cycles or undirected graphs without negative cycles.

I came across this example where the `rates` are the edges in an adjacency matrix and the `currencies` are the vertices (please let me know if I am misunderstanding).

```py
rates = [
    [1, 0.23, 0.25, 16.43, 18.21, 4.94],
    [4.34, 1, 1.11, 71.40, 79.09, 21.44],
    [3.93, 0.90, 1, 64.52, 71.48, 19.37],
    [0.061, 0.014, 0.015, 1, 1.11, 0.30],
    [0.055, 0.013, 0.014, 0.90, 1, 0.27],
    [0.20, 0.047, 0.052, 3.33, 3.69, 1],
]
 
currencies = ('PLN', 'EUR', 'USD', 'RUB', 'INR', 'MXN')
```

It looks like there is an edge to and from each vertex, which would make the graph undirected? There is probably something I am missing though as Bellman ford needs a directed graph to detect negative cycles.

[Here is the article I was reading with the full code example](https://anilpai.medium.com/currency-arbitrage-using-bellman-ford-algorithm-8938dcea56ea#:%7E:text=Bellman%20Ford%20algorithm%20can%20be,free%20transaction%20must%20act%20quick). The code is close to the bottom of the article.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here and if the graph is directed or undirected? If undirected, why does this work for arbitrage if it is looking for negative cycles?

Comment: "there is an edge to and from each vertex, which would make the graph undirected"  Nope.  If the edges are directed, the graph is directed, even if there happens to be two directed edges between every pair of nodes.  It would only become undirected if you replaced each pair of directed edges with one undirected edge.

Comment: Ahh ok, this makes sense, thank you. I was under the impression that if there exists a path to and from a vertex then it becomes undirected. So just to clarify, you are saying that it must be **one** edge that is undirected for the graph to become undirected. So as long as there is an edge from a to b and another edge from b to a, it is undirected?

Do you have any links that show concrete examples of code implementing each approach? It would be very helpful to solidify this.

Comment: Directed or undirected is an attribute of the data STRUCTURE used to store the graph not of the data stored in the data structure.  If you specify the graph to be directed, each link you add will be directed.  If you specify undirected, then each link will be undirected.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation! Do you know of any good links/resources that cover all these topics in depth? I am looking to learn as much depth as possible.

Comment: true..................................